# A PCI Express 3.0 Video Card into a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility, amd-radeon, pci-express

Perhaps I'm trying to push my mobo too hard, but I think I have read that PCI-e 3.0 is back compatible to previous PCI-e specifications. But 3.0 into a 1.0, is it possibly asking too much?

I'm thinking about buying an AMD [Radeon HD 7750](http://amzn.to.%20to/1iBJ1uU). My mobo is an Asus p5g41-m le

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, PCIe 3.0 is backward-compatible with all prior PCIe implementations.

Reference Wikipedia: [PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_3.0)

However, because PCIe 1.0 maxes out at 2.5 gigatransfers per second (GT/s) vs. PCIe 3.0's 8 GT/s, your video card may not perform as well as you would expect when installed in a PCIe 1.0 slot.

Comment: If the card doesn't work in a PCI-Express 1.0 slot, it's *not* a PCI-Express 3.0 card.

Comment: I rolled back my edit, but it still doesn't hurt to purchase from a seller with a generous return policy in case you're unfortunate enough to get a "PCI Express 3.0" card that isn't fully compliant with the spec.

Comment: It worked perfectly. So, yes, it's fully compatible.

Comment: And what about BIOS? I've heard some new videocards have BIOSes which are not compatible with mobos without UEFI BIOSes (which might include many older mobos with PCI Express v1.0)?

Comment: @JustAMartin, I'm not familiar with that issue but I suppose it's possible.