# New Graphics Card Preventing Boot Up

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, gpu

I have a pretty strange problem here and I would appreciate your help. I recently bought a new graphics card (MSi R9 390 8GB) and a new case as part of an ongoing upgrade to my existing, fairly ancient PC. I transferred all existing components to the new case and it works just fine - that is with all the components as they were in the old case.

When the new graphics card is inserted in place of the old one, I get an error message before I can even load the BIOS; "A bootable device has not been detected" and then a URL for Intel motherboard support. I don't think the GPU is faulty, because I am still getting an image on the screen. So what could it be? Could it be that the motherboard is simply too ancient for this GPU? Am I connecting power to the GPU incorrectly?

Things I have tried, among others:

- Resetting CMOS.
- Using Guru3D to make sure old drivers are deleted.
- Checked every connector - the computer works exactly as it should with the old GPU in place.
- Reseated the RAM.
- Updated motherboard BIOS to latest version.
- Checked every setting of new BIOS, PCI-E slot is selected, boot drives are in right order.
- Attempted to boot in safe mode.
- Disconnected and reconnected every drive between attempting to boot.

PC current specifications:

- Intel DP35DP Motherboard
- Intel Core 2 Duo 2.66GHz CPU
- Samsung SSD + 2x HDD Drives
- 4GB RAM
- Msi R9 390 8GB GPU (new)
- Msi GeForce 630 GPU (old - working)
- 750W PSU (within range for GPU and only a couple of weeks old)
- Windows 10 Pro 64bit (no install disc available)

Comment: the PSU can be too old (based on the age of the CPU, you use it for a long time) and maybe not able to provide the power the GPU needs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately the PSU is only a couple of weeks old, having bought it especially to power this new graphics card. I didn't make that clear in the question, so I will make an edit.

Comment: Are you sure that all power and data lines are connected to the drives? Because it would be very easy to forget a cable when you transfered the components to the new case. Or partially connect a cable. And thaT would trigger similar problems. That is assuming that you get the same message if you replace the new card with the old one.

Comment: `Could it be that the motherboard is simply too ancient for this GPU?`
This *should* not be the case.  PCE-e is backward compatible, Any PCI-e v1.0 card should work in a v1 slot or a v2 slot (at v1 speed). Ditto when you reverse it. Same for PCI-e v2 and v3 which should just work in any combination.  

And as far as I know the same holds for mixing PCIe v1 and V3.

Having written that, you do not seem to be the sole person with that problem. See

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2245208/intel-dp35dp-pci-compatibility.html  
https://communities.intel.com/thread/38635

Comment: [Theoretically it should work. However ....](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/349738-33-will-pcie-card-work)

[PCI Express 3.0 Base specification revision 3.0 ...  it would be backward compatible with existing PCIe implementations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_3.0)

And a confirmation here on [su] that it can work.
http://superuser.com/questions/427196/a-pci-express-3-0-video-card-into-a-pci-e-1-0-x16-slot

Comment: @Hennes The problem disappears when using my old graphics card, so I am guessing it is some incompatibility between my motherboard and graphics card. Thank you for those links, it does seem to be an issue with this motherboard in particular. I was planning on holding off on a motherboard + processor upgrade for a few months, but looks like I'll need to splash out sooner than I thought!

Comment: Might be worth looking for a BIOS update before buying a new motherboard. Maybe they fixed it. (Assuming you have an older version then released on 28/09/2010)

Comment: ok, this was not clear, that the PSU is new. So try the suggested BIOS Update first

Comment: Having installed the [latest chipset](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/10884/Chipset-Intel-Chipset-Device-Software-for-Discontinued-Intel-Desktop-Boards) and the [latest BIOS](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/17930/BIOS-Update-DPP3510J-86A-) the card is unfortunately still not working. I get the feeling a new motherboard might be the way forward. At least I can still use the old card in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue, so I am posting for anyone who might have the same problem.

Despite PCI-E being backwards compatible, there was an issue with my particular model of motherboard (Intel DP35DP) making it incompatible with the graphics card, even after updating the BIOS.

My solution was to buy a new motherboard, and this solved the issue completely.